# Is there a way to only push routes via OpenVPN under certain conditions?

Tags: routing, openvpn, conditional

**Abstract question:**
In my OpenVPN client setup I'd like to set routes pushed by the server only under certain conditions.

**Concrete situation:**
I am using a laptop, that, when I am at the office, connects to our companys infrastructure via its gateway. When I am out of the office, e.g. at a customers site, I use a separate OpenVPN connection to reach our infrastructure. The twist here is, that this OpenVPN connection is also used to connect to our customers, either when I am in the office, or when I am on the road.

The routes to our customers networks and our infrastructures network get pushed everytime I connect the OpenVPN client on my laptop. There is an application running in our datacenter which gets pretty confused by the second connection, and I would like it only to use the route via our offices gateway, when I am in the office.

**Question:** Is there any option in OpenVPN to tell the client something like *"if you have an IP adress assigned like 10.0.0.X (office-site IP address), do **NOT** apply one specific route pushed from the server (the route that points to our infrastructure / datacenter)"*.

All other routes should not be affected by the workaround / solution and the route should be pushed, when I am working from a customers site or from my home office.
I cannot set up another connection that does not include the route to the datacenter, as the connection is used by co-workers too.

**Researches done so far:** I already worked through FAQs and manpages of OpenVPN, where I found solutions pointing to only route specific traffic or all traffic through the VPN, which is as good as setting up another connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the directive `route-noexec` and manually set up the routing with `up` and `down` scripts on this specific client.

You should have all required information in environment variables, see section `Environmental Variables` in the manpage.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two different .opvn files in the client that you use depending on your situation. Then in one of these .opvpn files you could use the `route-nopull` directive and use custom alternative routes ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698215/not-route-all-traffic-through-the-vpn-how-to-change-ovpn-file#answer-35700325)).

It's not perfect, but it's the best I could come up with.